# How to get Java targetCompatibility from build.gradle via gradle command line

Tags: java, gradle

Hey I have a java project setup with gradle, in my file I have something like:

```
tasks {
    // Set the JVM compatibility versions
    withType<JavaCompile> {
        sourceCompatibility = "21"
        targetCompatibility = "21"
    }
...
```

For my CI I want to download the proper JDK to compile my code is there a way to get the java version using gradle CLI?

I tried with  `./gradlew properties` and I do get some values with source and target compatibility but it seems to be independent of whatever I put in my build.gradle.kts (is probably the version set by my current gradle version not my project)

Thanks!

Comment: assuming that you want to read the compatibility flag from build.gradle before running the build - going the shell function (grep / awk) may be the way, OR you can try Toolchains - see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html#toolchains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Gradle CLI doesn't have a built-in or plug-in observer to retrieve information like Maven does via the [Apache Maven Help Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/evaluate-mojo.html).

But if you have the ability to modify Gradle build scripts, you can write your own tasks, for example:

```
tasks.register("javaSourceCompatibility") {
    doLast {
        val compileJava = tasks.getByName("compileJava", JavaCompile::class)
        print(compileJava.sourceCompatibility)
    }
}

tasks.register("javaTargetCompatibility") {
    doLast {
        val compileJava = tasks.getByName("compileJava", JavaCompile::class)
        print(compileJava.targetCompatibility)
    }
}
```

And get information from them as follows:

```
./gradlew -q --console=plain javaSourceCompatibility
./gradlew -q --console=plain javaTargetCompatibility
```

Note that the `-q` and `--console=plain` flags are needed to hide all other information except what that the tasks print.

If you need to propagate these changes across multiple projects, I recommend you to create a Gradle plugin which will automatically include these tasks in any project.